# Flash Player sub or dot version penetration?

Tags: statistics, flash

Adobe publishes Flash player penetrations stats but ONLY for major player versions.

Does anyone know if anyone publishes stats on sub versions? ie am interested in current penetration of FP 10.3

Answer (score 1):

According to http://riastats.com/, at least 95% of PC's have Flash Player 10 or better, of which 52% are Flash Player 10.3.

[Adobe's](http://www.adobe.com/products/player_census/flashplayer/version_penetration.html) stats are close enough to riastats figures (99% vs 95%) to not make a difference.